# Pick a Random Images and Do PIL for Watermark

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've error when i pick a random image in a folder and i want to edit with PIL.

My code is

```
import os
import random
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

def watermark_text(input_image_path,
                   output_image_path,
                   text, pos):
    photo = Image.open(input_image_path)

    # make the image editable
    drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)

    black = (255, 255, 255)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("font.ttf", 40)
    drawing.text(pos, text, fill=black, font=font)
    photo.show()
    photo.save(output_image_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path="./bg"
    files=os.listdir(path)
    d=random.choice(files)
    img = d
    watermark_text(img, '1.jpg',
                   text='Risna Fadillah',
                   pos=(0, 0))
```

and error showing like this

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "quotes.py", line 26, in 
> watermark_text(img, '1.jpg',
> File "quotes.py", line 10, in watermark_text
> photo = Image.open(input_image_path)
> File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2878, in open
> fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")                          FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1qqq.jpg'

How to fix it?

Comment: The error is saying that python could not find`1.jpg`. The Image must be in the same directory as your  python script. If it still isn't working using the full path of the image should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was careless about this, I should have written like this

```
import os
import random
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

def watermark_text(input_image_path,
                   output_image_path,
                   text, pos):
    photo = Image.open(input_image_path)

    # make the image editable
    drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)

    black = (255, 255, 255)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("font.ttf", 40)
    drawing.text(pos, text, fill=black, font=font)
    photo.show()
    photo.save(output_image_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path="./bg/"
    files=os.listdir(path)
    d=random.choice(files)
    img = path + d
    watermark_text(img, '1.jpg',
                   text='Risna Fadillah',
                   pos=(0, 0))
```

sorry.